# Export a list of objects in typescript, and dynamically import them a react component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a object containing a key / value pair of name / component in a tsx file.

// icons.tsx

```
import { BirdIcon, CatIcon } from 'components/Icons';

interface Map {
  [key: string]: string | undefined;
}

export const Icons: Map = {
  birds: <BirdIcon />,
  cats: <CatIcon />,
};
```

I'm getting an error in the object saying

> Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)

I'm trying to dynamically import this into my next.js comopnent and I'm getting the following error

```
const DynamicComponent = dynamic(() =>
  import('./Icons/').then((mod) => mod.Icons),
);
```

I'm getting the following error

> ```
>     Type 'Map' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<{}> | { default: ComponentType<{}>; }'.
> ```

Any suggestions here?

Comment: `next/dynamic` should return a React component but `mod.Icons` is an object.

Answer (score 0):

Change your interface to :

```
interface Map {
  [key: string]: React.Component<{}> | undefined;
}
```

Also, you need to select one of the components from the map, because it is expected in dynamic.

Comment: I'm getting this error on the key now >Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'Component<{}, {}, any>'.ts(2322)